# How to create combobox with combobox inside using PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

For example suppose I have this dictionary - `dict = {a: 1,2,3, b: 4,5,6, c: 7,8,9}`
how can I create combobox for dict with comboboxes for dict's values ?

[image]

Comment: Create two comboboxes, populate first with dictionary keys, and repopulate second when item selected in first combobox with appropriate values

Comment: but, can I do it with only one combobox object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a **Nested Menu**.

[image]

One way to do that in Qt is to use a `QToolButton` with a `QMenu`

```
d = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9]}

button = QToolButton()

def callback_factory(k, v):
    return lambda: button.setText('{0}_{1}'.format(k, v))

menu = QMenu()
for k, vals in d.items():
    sub_menu = menu.addMenu(k)
    for v in vals:
        action = sub_menu.addAction(str(v))
        action.triggered.connect(callback_factory(k, v))

button.setMenu(menu)
```

Comment: Please, help me one more time. How to get (or see) a selected value in that menu ?

Comment: You'll have to store the selection when they click it. You can do that in the function returned from the callback_factory that gets executed when they click the item